# ¿Como imprimir del 1 al 100 en ensamblador usando el entorno del debug con el programa del dos box?

Tags: ensamblador

estoy intentando programar del 1 al 100 en el entorno del debug por ejemplo:

E:/> DEBUG

-A //empezar a ensamblar

073F:0100 [aqui se empieza]

Yo tengo esto pero solo imprime el 1:

```
MOV CX, 64  ; Configura el contador CX a 64 (100 en decimal)
MOV AH, 2   ; Configura la función de servicio AH a 2 (para mostrar el carácter)
MOV DL, 31  ; Configura DL con el valor hexadecimal del número 1
MOV BH, 0   ; Configura BH a 0 (página de visualización)
INT 21      ; Llama a la interrupción 21 para mostrar el carácter
INC DL      ; Incrementa el valor en DL para el próximo número
LOOP        ; Repite el bucle hasta que CX sea igual a cero
INT 20      ; Termina el programa y vuelve al sistema operativo
```

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado? ¿Qué errores tienes? Recuerda el [Ejemplo Mínimo Verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) de lo que has hecho y fundamentalmente parte del código que has utilizado (en texto, no imagen) que se menciona en el [tour] y en [ask].

Comment: Bienvenido. El procesador determina el conjunto de instrucciones. Cada sistema operativo tiene su forma de hacer llamadas al kernel. No podemos ayudarte sin saber esos detalles.